# Can we have an array of activities?

Tags: android

hey im doing a project at the moment which is a note app , the main activty is basically a listview which should contain different notes that the user write .

My question is as follows: what type of array should I create so that it contains different objects of the "writing note" activity and when the user click on one of them it takes him to the notes that he has written previously ?

I tried making objects of the activity like how we do it with normal classes but it 
did not work .
my question might be silly but im new to android and im lost in this case,thanks.

Comment: you should use views not activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making a single Activity for viewing notes. Whenever you select one of the saved notes it always opens the same Activity class, but the content in the Activity is filled from the specific note.

You can pass the data from the note to the Activity with Intents and putExtra()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra

Answer (score 0):

You use a `ListView` for this kind of problem. When you click on one item of the `ListView` a new Activity "pops up".

But I think the question is, which array to use for the Adapter of the ListView. I would create a custom object, where you save the data you need for your fragments/activities. You use the data from the `CustomObjects` to start a new activity/fragment when you click on one item on the ListView. You then have to make your `Adapter<CustomObject>` and pass it to your ListView.

Comment: can you explain the points where u said " You use the data from the CustomObjects to start a new activity/fragment when you click on one item on the ListView."more? im having a trouble understanding how the Activity is going to know from which object the user is coming so that it adjusts the data in the right way. Also since im going to have the save activity opens how to manipulate it so that it shows a blank page if the user is creating new note or to retrieve previous note if it already exists? Thank you for responding

Comment: Well as you use a ListView, you probably have an Adapter which builds each item of the list with the item you passed on this position in the Array to the Adapter. You can save the data from your Notes in a NotesObject and access it from the Adapter. In onClick you can access this data and build a new activity, which you start from there, with this data

Comment: If you want to add a blank note at "Create New" you probably better implement a button and in onClick () of this button you start a new Activity (on a complete new screen) or you could add a new Fragment/View to your actual Activity, where you can write notes.

Comment: thank you very much i managed to do it somehow